# About speed of procedures between user-made and built-in in scheme (related with SICP exercise 1.23)

Tags: algorithm, scheme, time-complexity, primes, sicp

//My question was so long So I reduced.

In scheme, user-made procedures consume more time than built-in procedures?
(If both's functions are same)

//This is my short version question.
//Below is long long version question.

EX 1.23 is problem(below), why the (next) procedure isn't twice faster than (+ 1)?

This is my guess.

reason 1 : (next) contains 'if' (special-form) and it consumes time.

reason 2 : function call consumes time.

http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-1.23 says reason 1 is right.

And I want to know reason 2 is also right.

SO I rewrote the (next) procedure. I didn't use 'if' and checked the number divided by 2 just once before use (next)(so (next) procedure only do + 2). And I remeasured the time. It was more fast than before BUT still not 2. SO I rewrote again. I changed (next) to (+ num 2). Finally It became 2 or almost 2. And I thought why. This is why I guess the 'reason 2'. I want to know what is correct answer.

ps. I'm also curious about why some primes are being tested (very?) fast than others? It doesn't make sense because if a number n is prime, process should see from 2 to sqrt(n). But some numbers are tested faster. Do you know why some primes are tested faster?

Exercise 1.23.  The smallest-divisor procedure shown at the start of this section does lots of needless testing: After it checks to see if the number is divisible by 2 there is no point in checking to see if it is divisible by any larger even numbers. This suggests that the values used for test-divisor should not be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., but rather 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, .... To implement this change, define a procedure next that returns 3 if its input is equal to 2 and otherwise returns its input plus 2. Modify the smallest-divisor procedure to use (next test-divisor) instead of (+ test-divisor 1). With timed-prime-test incorporating this modified version of smallest-divisor, run the test for each of the 12 primes found in exercise 1.22. Since this modification halves the number of test steps, you should expect it to run about twice as fast. Is this expectation confirmed? If not, what is the observed ratio of the speeds of the two algorithms, and how do you explain the fact that it is different from 2?

Where the book is :
http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your long ans short questions are actually addressing two different problems.

> EX 1.23 is problem(below), why the (next) procedure isn't twice faster than (+ 1)?

You provide two possible reasons to explain the relative lack of speed up (and 30% speed gain is already a good achievement):

- The apparent use of a function `next` instead of a simple arithmetic expression (as I understand it from your explanations),
- the inclusion of a test in that very `next` function,

The first reason is an illusion: `(+ 1)` is a function incrementing its argument, so in both cases there is a function call (although the increment function is certainly a builtin one, a point which is addressed by your other question).

The second reason is indeed relevant: any test in a block of code will introduce a potential redirection in the code flow (a jump from the current executing instruction to some other address in the program), which may incur a delay. Note that this is analogous to a function call, which will also induce an address jump, so both reasons actually resolve to only one potential cause.

Regarding your short question, builtin functions are indeed usually faster, because the compiler is able to apply a special treatment to them in certain cases. This is due to the facts that:

- knowing the *semantics* of the builtins, compiler designers are able to include special rules pertaining to the algebraic properties of these builtins, and for instance fuse successive incréments in a single call, or suppress a combination of increment and decrement called in sequence.
- A builtin function call, when not optimised away, will be converted into a native machine code function call, which may not have to abide to all the calling convention rules. If your scheme compiler produce machine code from the source, then there might be only a marginal gain, but if it produce so called bytecode, the gain might be quite substantial, since user written functions will be translated to that bytecode format, and still require some form of interpretation. If you are only using an interpreter, then the gain is even more important.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is highly implementation and setting dependent. In many implementations there are different kinds of optimizations and in some there are none. To get the best performance you may need to compile your code or use settings to reduce debug information / stack traces. Getting the best performance in one implementation can worsen the performance in another.

Primitive procedures are usually compiled to be native and in some implementations, like ikarus, it's even inlined. (When you do `(map car lst)` ikarus changes it to `(map (lambda (x) (car x)) lst)` since `car` isn't a procedure) Lambdas are supposed to be cheap.. Remember many scheme implementations change your code to CPS and that is one procedure call for each expression in the body of a procedure call. It will never be as fast as machine code since it needs to do load closure variables.

To check which of the two options which are correct for your implementation make `next` do the same as it originally did. eg. no `if` but just increment the argument. The difference now is the extra call and nothing else. Then you can inline `next` by writing it's code directly in your procedure and substituting arguments for the operands. Is it still slower, then it's `if`. you need to run the tests several times, preferably with large enough number of primes to produce that it runs for a minute or so. Use `time` or similar in both the Scheme implementations to get the differences in ms. I use unix `time` command as well to see how the OS reflects on it.

You should also test to see if you get the same reason in some other implementation. It's not like it's not enough Scheme implementations out there so know yourself out! The differences between them might amaze you. I always use racket (`raco exe source` to make executable) and Ikarus. WHen doing a large test I include Chicken, Gambit and Chibi.